# Multiple SQL Counts in with multiple criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, count

I've been trying to optimise the way I retrieve data from my database for display on a "dashboard" type of page for software development

My database structure is as follows:

- Requirements Table that contains all the various requirements with various fields, but importantly a REQ_ID as key.
- Tasks Table that contains can contain multiple tasks with a TASK_ID, TASK_NAME (DEV, TEST OR RELEASE), TASK_STATUS (Not Started, Complete, Blocked), TASK_WINDOW (Week1, Week2, .. etc. when task was completed) and a link back to a requirement with REQ_I. For example, a requirement may have multiple dev tasks, test tasks and  release tasks but for can only be dev complete if all the dev tasks related to a requirement is complete, otherwise it is incomplete

I would like to query these two tables to provide me a results set that contains individually the number DEV Complete, Test Complete and Release Complete requirements per DEV task window in a single query. I'm currently performing multiple query each containing subqueries and then aggregating the results with PHP, however this in total takes 15 sec to exec, Can anybody please help me in consolidating this into a single query>

Answer (score 11):

```
SELECT r.REQ_ID, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN t.TASK_NAME = 'DEV' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS DevComplete,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t.TASK_NAME = 'TEST' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TestComplete,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t.TASK_NAME = 'RELEASE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ReleaseComplete
    FROM Requirements r
        INNER JOIN Tasks t
            ON r.REQ_ID = t.REQ_ID
    WHERE t.TASK_STATUS = 'Complete'
    GROUP BY r.REQ_ID
```

Comment: +1 - Good old `SUM(CASE...`.  Is there anything it **can't** fix?

Comment: You should be able to eliminate the join and just group off of t.REQ_ID

Comment: @JNK: Indeed. I was at SQL Saturday 67 this weekend where [Kevin Boles](https://twitter.com/#!/TheSQLGuru) gave a session on [Advanced TSQL Solutions](http://www.sqlsaturday.com/viewsession.aspx?sat=67&sessionid=3503) and said "CASE" was his favorite 4-letter word in SQL. I'd have to agree with him there.

Comment: @gcooney: I wanted to leave the query open to the possibility that other columns from the Requirements table might be needed.

Comment: @Joe Stefanelli Fair enough.  If other columns were needed the join would certainly be necessary.  If not, removing the join could be an optimization.

Comment: @all, thank you, i have made a change to the question, I omitted the fact that for a requirement to be either DEV, TASK or RELEASE complete all the specific task need to be complete, how would this be managed inside the query? (For example, a requirement may have multiple dev tasks, test tasks and  release tasks but for example can only be dev complete if all the dev tasks related to a requirement is complete, otherwise it is incomplet)

Comment: @Joe Stefanelli, thank you, I also need it to be grouped by the TASK_WINDOW of TASK (DEV) as I want it to always relate to when the development was done.

Comment: @JoeStefanelli Thank you! i actually want to give +10000. Thanks for solving it

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old question but I ran a test with the following patterns:

**Pattern 1:**

```
SELECT
 [Count1] = SUM(CASE WHEN ... THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
 [Count2] = SUM(CASE WHEN ... THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM
 [Table]
GROUP BY
 [Field]
```

**Pattern 2:**

```
SELECT
  [COUNT1] = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Table] WHERE ...),
  [Count2] = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Table] WHERE ...)
```

In my case, when running both queries, pattern 2 took 36 % of the time and pattern 1 took 64%.  To me, pattern 1 looks more elegant, but it didn't perform nearly as well in my scenario.